# Как связать переменную в ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

**Всем привет!**

Не так давно я задавал вопрос по поводу связывание внутри ng-repeat. Проблема была в том, что внутри блока с ng-repeat angular создает собственный scope для переменных внутри него и никак не привязывает их к переменным в scope контроллера. Вот пример кода представления:

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    <input ng-model="newItemName">
</li>
```

Не смотря на то, что в scope контроллера есть переменная newItemName, она никак не связана с той, что используется в input.
Проблему я решил следующим образом:

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    <input ng-model="$parent.newItemName">
</li>
```

Таким образом angular не создает собственный экземпляр newItemName, а привязывает к переменной в scope контроллера.
Но, когда я решил вынести эту лишку в отдельную директиву, почему-то такой подход перестал работать (angular больше не привязывает эту переменную к той, что находится в scope контроллера), не смотря на то, что в свойстве scope директивы стоит true.

Не подскажете, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Прочитать про прототпипное наследование.
2. Привязывать к полям объектов.
3. Такое использование привязки внутри ng-repeat к тому, что не принадлежит повторяемому элементу очень сильно скажется на производительности. Уже один раз такую гадость правил. Правда, правил ещё одним ng-repeat, но это был костыль вместо ng-if.

Comment: // А можно нумеровать пункты списка с нуля?

Comment: Да, помнится, как-то экспериментировал с привязкой к полю объекта, но такой вариант меня не устроил. 
Что касается третьего пункта, то возможно вы правы, но альтернативного способа без манипулирования элементами DOM я не нашел.
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А почему при использовании директивы перестал работать старый метод не знаете?

Comment: @Antoshka004, в смысле, не нашёл? Зачем в каждом повторяемом элементе редактировать то, что ему не принадлежит? И какой старый метод работать перестал?

Comment: У меня есть список проектов, которые можно редактировать. Соответственно каждому из таких проектов нужна форма редактирования. Раньше я просто вырывал форму из одного места документа и вставлял ее в нужную лишку. Может такой вариант и лучше, но потом я решил добавить каждому из проектов свой блок редактирования, и показывать его тогда, когда проект редактируется. Выглядит это примерно так - http://joxi.ru/5md06qgIyvKXm1.

Comment: До использования собственной директивы, которая представляет из себя сам проект все работала с помощью обращения через $parent. Но как только я поместил лишку в шаблон директивы, такой метод перестал работать.

Comment: @Antoshka004, так почему, есои надо редактировать конкретный элемент, ng-model ведёт на скоуп, а не на этот элемент?

Comment: Не знаю, изначально завел переменные, которые буду хранить новые значения. Не думал, что столкнусь с подобной проблемой. 
Почему-то даже в голову не пришло сохранять старое значение в какой-нибудь переменной, а редактировать сам объект. Я так понял, вы это имеете в виду. А это идея! Спасибо!

Comment: @Antoshka004, смотри, что будет, если твоя штука заработает. У тебя повторяется, например, 100 элементов. А ссылка в ng-model ведёт куда-то там. Теперь, при изменении в одном месте - пользователь просто буковку нажал, срабатывает изменение, которое видят 99 других ng-model, обрабатывают и меняют 99 текстовых полей, которые пользователь даже не видит. Это жууууутко медленно и тормозит при каждом нажатии клавиши. Поэтому так делать не надо. Либо, оборачивать всё в ng-if, чтобы лишнее даже в разметку не попадало.

Comment: Все лишнее у меня скрыто под ng-hide, так нормально? Одновременно можно может быть активен только один input.
Попробовал привязать к самому объекту, обнаружил одно неудобное последствие. Удобнее было бы сохранять результат только после нажатия кнопки сохранить, как это было реализовано раньше. А теперь получается, что результат не сохраняется, только при нажатии кнопки "Отмена". А при всех других действиях сохраняется, что довольно неудобно, мне кажется.

Comment: Так вот как все-таки посоветуете поступить, работать именно с самим объектом и при каждом действии отличном от "Сохранить", сбрасывать значение переменной (в моем случае project.name = oldProjectName) или оставить связывание со сторонней переменной, являющейся свойством определенного объекта (чтобы связывание работало) при условии, что одновременно может быть только один input для изменения ng-model?

Comment: @Antoshka004, как тебе удобнее, так и делай.

Comment: @Antoshka004, "Все лишнее у меня скрыто под ng-hide, так нормально?" - нет. В таком варианте всё равно существует по инпуту на каждый повторяемый элемент.

Comment: А ng-if решает эту проблему?

Comment: @Antoshka004, да.